# How do I combine a range query with a keyword query in Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Given this domain model:

```java
class User { // <- this is the root entity
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Set<UserSkill> skills = new HashSet<>();
}

class UserSkill {
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Skill skill;

    @Enumerated
    @Field(bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = EnumAsIntegerBridge.class))
    private UserSkillLevel level;
}

class Skill {
    @Field
    private String name;
}
```

How can I use a range query combined with a term query to search for users who have a particular skill with a given level?

I tried this query to look for users who have advanced React skills:

```java
var q = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
q.add(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("skills.skill.name").matching("React").createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
q.add(queryBuilder.range().onField("skills.level").above(UserSkillLevel.ADVANCED.ordinal()).createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
var finalQuery = q.build();
```

What this returns:

- Users who have a React skill (regardless of level) *AND*
- Users who have an advanced skill or higher (regardless of skill name).

What I expected it to return:

- Users who have a React skill that is advanced or higher.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-search#7-range-queries this might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you never mentioned that the two constraints (skill name and skill level) must apply to the same skill. That's why you got this result.

In Hibernate Search 5, there is no support for that kind of "join". The best you can do is to index the skill name and skill level in a single field (concatenated), but that's a bit of a hack.

In Hibernate Search 6, there is support for *nested* fields, which solve this problem. However, the API of Hibernate Search 6 is very different.

Here is how to achieve what you want in Hibernate Search 6.

```java
@Indexed
class User {
    @IndexedEmbedded(storage = ObjectStorage.NESTED) // Notice this change
    private Set<UserSkill> skills = new HashSet<>();
}

class UserSkill {
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Skill skill;

    @Enumerated
    @GenericField(valueBridge = @ValueBridge(impl = EnumAsIntegerBridge.class)) // This changed too
    private UserSkillLevel level;
}

class Skill {
    @FullTextField(analyzer = "standard") // You will have to define this analyzer, see the getting started guide
    private String name;
}

// New implementation of your bridge
class EnumAsIntegerValueBridge implements ValueBridge<Enum<?>, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer toIndexedValue(Enum<?> enum) {
        return enum.ordinal();
    }
}
```

Then the query:

```java
List<User> hits = Search.session(entityManager).search(User.class)
        .where(f -> f.nested().onField("skills").nest(f.bool()
                .must(f.match().field("skills.skill.name").matching("React"))
                .must(f.range().field("skills.level").atLeast(UserSkillLevel.ADVANCED))))
        .fetchHits(20);
```

Note that you will need to update your dependencies (groupId, artifactId and version). You might want to have a look at the [getting started guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started) first.